# how to add the multiple input text value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

```js
//my jquery
//get the amount and calculate the total amount

$('#dynamicDiv').on('keyup', '.getAmount', function(event) {
   var total = 0;
   $(this).each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value,10);
   });
```

```html
<div id="dynamicDiv">
<div class="row form-group delDiv">
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Name: </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Amount: </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control getAmount">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm newDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add new row"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm removeDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete current row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
   <div class="row form-group delDiv">
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Name: </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Amount: </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control getAmount">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm newDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add new row"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm removeDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete current row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
</div> <!-- parent div end -->
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row ">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-5 control-label"><b>Allowance Total:</b> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control totalAmount">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i feel this is complex, i want to add the multiple input text value and display in the total amount text value.so that the total sum of the input value. I have jQuery what's wrong with this. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$(this).each` ? `this` will return `element` on which event is invoked... try `$('.getAmount').each`

Comment: @Rayon .getAmount class, you check the input tag, i declare the class called getAmount.

Comment: @Rayon whenever keypress means new amount(like 123) is added, it should be added with the previous value and show the total sum(final amount

Comment: why minus vote, what's wrong with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$(this).each(function() {`, `this` will return `element` on which event is invoked.
Use`$('.getAmount')` selector to get value of all the elements having class as `getAmount`

Note: Also use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of `keyup`

```js
$('#dynamicDiv').on('input', '.getAmount', function(event) {
  var total = 0;
  $('.getAmount').each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
    //consider || condition as `parseInt('')` is `NaN` or use `Number(this.value)`
  });
  $('.totalAmount').val(total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamicDiv">
  <div class="row form-group delDiv">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Amount:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control getAmount">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm newDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add new row"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm removeDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete current row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group delDiv">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Allowance Amount:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control getAmount">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm newDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add new row"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm removeDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete current row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- parent div end -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label"><b>Allowance Total:</b> 
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control totalAmount">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it work, i changed the some, your idea works thanks           (this.value || 0, 10) can you explain this please, i need to know

Comment: @Rakesh, If value of the input is `''`, then in `.each`, `parseInt('')` will be `NaN`.. Using `||`, we are using OR value if `this.value` is falsey value..